# Display shipping options conditionally in multiple packages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

So I am using a plugin to create multiple packages for my products, as each class has different shipping options.
e.g a belt is delivered by post and a washing machine is delivered by van

I am also using a filter to remove the shipping options I don't need, depending on the shipping class.
e.g. a belt doesn't need the deliver by van option, and the washing machine doesn't need the deliver by post option

However, I am having trouble combining the two when there is more than one item in my cart. The current system eliminates all of the unnecessary shipping options from the first item in the cart, and applies the filter across all items.

I need a way for the filter to apply itself by checking for the shipping class in each package rather than from the cart (before the packages are called)

Here is my filter: (I just repeat the filter for the different shipping classes)

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'wf_hide_shipping_method_based_on_miele_freestanding_shipping_class', 10, 2);

function wf_hide_shipping_method_based_on_miele_freestanding_shipping_class($available_shipping_methods, $package)
{
    $hide_when_shipping_class_exist = array(
        4048 => array(
            'flat_rate:17',                 // set the options you want to hide when this class is in the basket
        'flat_rate:23',
        'flat_rate:22',
        'flat_rate:21',
        'local_pickup:25',
        'free_shipping:16'
        )
    );    

    $shipping_class_in_cart = array();
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $key => $values) {
       $shipping_class_in_cart[] = $values['data']->get_shipping_class_id();
    }

    foreach($hide_when_shipping_class_exist as $class_id => $methods) {
        if(in_array($class_id, $shipping_class_in_cart)){
            foreach($methods as & $current_method) {
                unset($available_shipping_methods[$current_method]);
            }
        }
    }
    foreach($hide_when_shipping_class_not_exist as $class_id => $methods) {
        if(!in_array($class_id, $shipping_class_in_cart)){
            foreach($methods as & $current_method) {
                unset($available_shipping_methods[$current_method]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $available_shipping_methods;
}
```

And here is the plugin:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'woocommerce_multiple_packaging_init', 106);
function woocommerce_multiple_packaging_init() {

    /**
     * Check if WooCommerce is active
     */
    if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) || class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {

        if ( !class_exists( 'BE_Multiple_Packages' ) ) {

            // Include Necessary files
            require_once('class-settings.php');
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages', array( 'BE_Multiple_Packages', 'generate_packages' ) );

            class BE_Multiple_Packages {

                /**
                 * Constructor.
                 */
                public function __construct() {
                    $settings_class = new BE_Multiple_Packages_Settings();
                    $settings_class->get_package_restrictions();
                    $this->package_restrictions = $settings_class->package_restrictions;
                }


                /**
                 * Get Settings for Restrictions Table
                 *
                 * @access public
                 * @return void
                 */
                function generate_packages( $packages ) {
                    if( get_option( 'multi_packages_enabled' ) ) {
                        // Reset the packages
                        $packages = array();
                        $settings_class = new BE_Multiple_Packages_Settings();
                        $package_restrictions = $settings_class->package_restrictions;
                        $free_classes = get_option( 'multi_packages_free_shipping' );

                        // Determine Type of Grouping
                        if( get_option( 'multi_packages_type' ) == 'per-product' ) :
                            // separate each item into a package
                            $n = 0;
                            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
                                if ( $item['data']->needs_shipping() ) {
                                    // Put inside packages
                                    $packages[ $n ] = array(
                                        'contents' => array($item),
                                        'contents_cost' => array_sum( wp_list_pluck( array($item), 'line_total' ) ),
                                        'applied_coupons' => WC()->cart->applied_coupons,
                                        'destination' => array(
                                            'country' => WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(),
                                            'state' => WC()->customer->get_shipping_state(),
                                            'postcode' => WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode(),
                                            'city' => WC()->customer->get_shipping_city(),
                                            'address' => WC()->customer->get_shipping_address(),
                                            'address_2' => WC()->customer->get_shipping_address_2()
                                        )
                                    );

                                    // Determine if 'ship_via' applies
                                    $key = $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id();
                                    if( $free_classes && in_array( $key, $free_classes ) ) {
                                        $packages[ $n ]['ship_via'] = array('free_shipping');
                                    } elseif( count( $package_restrictions ) && isset( $package_restrictions[ $key ] ) ) {
                                        $packages[ $n ]['ship_via'] = $package_restrictions[ $key ];
                                    }
                                    $n++;
                                }
                            }

                        else :
                            // Create arrays for each shipping class
                            $shipping_classes = $other = array();
                            $get_classes = WC()->shipping->get_shipping_classes();
                            foreach ( $get_classes as $key => $class ) {
                                $shipping_classes[ $class->term_id ] = $class->slug;
                                $array_name = $class->slug;
                                $$array_name = array();
                            }
                            $shipping_classes['misc'] = 'other';

                            // Sort bulky from regular
                            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
                                if ( $item['data']->needs_shipping() ) {
                                    $item_class = $item['data']->get_shipping_class();
                                    if( isset( $item_class ) && $item_class != '' ) {
                                        foreach ($shipping_classes as $class_id => $class_slug) {
                                            if ( $item_class == $class_slug ) {
                                                array_push( $$class_slug, $item );
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        $other[] = $item;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            // Put inside packages
                            $n = 0;
                            foreach ($shipping_classes as $key => $value) {
                                if ( count( $$value ) ) {
                                    $packages[ $n ] = array(
                                        'contents' => $$value,
                                        'contents_cost' => array_sum( wp_list_pluck( $$value, 'line_total' ) ),
                                        'applied_coupons' => WC()->cart->applied_coupons,
                                        'destination' => array(
                                            'country' => WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(),
                                            'state' => WC()->customer->get_shipping_state(),
                                            'postcode' => WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode(),
                                            'city' => WC()->customer->get_shipping_city(),
                                            'address' => WC()->customer->get_shipping_address(),
                                            'address_2' => WC()->customer->get_shipping_address_2()
                                        )
                                    );

                                    // Determine if 'ship_via' applies
                                    if( $free_classes && in_array( $key, $free_classes ) ) {
                                        $packages[ $n ]['ship_via'] = array('free_shipping');
                                    } elseif( count( $package_restrictions ) && isset( $package_restrictions[ $key ] ) ) {
                                        $packages[ $n ]['ship_via'] = $package_restrictions[ $key ];
                                    }
                                    $n++;
                                }
                            }

                        endif;

                        return $packages;
                    }
                }

            } // end class BE_Multiple_Packages

        } // end IF class 'BE_Multiple_Packages' exists

    } // end IF woocommerce exists

    add_filter( 'plugin_action_links_' . plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'be_multiple_packages_plugin_action_links' );

    function be_multiple_packages_plugin_action_links( $links ) {
        return array_merge(
            array(
                'settings' => '<a href="' . get_bloginfo( 'wpurl' ) . '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=multiple_packages">Settings</a>',
                'support' => '<a href="http://bolderelements.net/" target="_blank">Bolder Elements</a>'
            ),
            $links
        );
    }

} // end function: woocommerce_multiple_packaging_init
```

EDIT: the associated class_settings file for the plugin;

```
<?php
/**
 * WooCommerce Multiple Packages Settings Page
 *
 * @author      Erica Dion
 * @category    Classes
 * @package     WooCommerce-Multiple-Packaging
 * @version     1.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly
if ( ! class_exists( 'BE_Multiple_Packages_Settings' ) ) :
include_once( WC()->plugin_path().'/includes/admin/settings/class-wc-settings-page.php' );
class BE_Multiple_Packages_Settings extends WC_Settings_Page {

/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public function __construct() {
    global $woocommerce;

    $this->id = 'multiple_packages';
    $this->version = '1.1';
    $this->label = __( 'Multiple Packages', 'bolder-multi-package-woo' );
    $this->multi_package_restrictions = 'bolder_multi_package_woo_restrictions';

    $this->get_package_restrictions();

    parent::__construct();

    //add_filter( 'woocommerce_settings_tabs_array', array( $this, 'add_settings_page' ), 82 );
    //add_action( 'woocommerce_settings_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'output' ) );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_field_shipping_restrictions', array( $this, 'output_additional_settings' ) );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option_shipping_restrictions', array( $this, 'sanitize_shipping_restrictions_field' ), 15, 3 );
    //add_action( 'woocommerce_settings_save_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'save' ) );
    //add_action( 'woocommerce_sections_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'output_sections' ) );
    //add_action( 'woocommerce_sections_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'additional_output' ) );

}

/**
 * Output the settings
 */
public function output() {

    $settings = $this->get_settings( );
    WC_Admin_Settings::output_fields( $settings );
}

/**
 * Save settings
 */
public function save() {

    $settings = $this->get_settings( );
    WC_Admin_Settings::save_fields( $settings );
    //$this->save_additional_settings();
}


/**
 * Get Page Settings
 *
 * @return array
 */
function get_settings( $current_section = '' ) {

    $shipping_classes = array();
    $get_classes = WC()->shipping->get_shipping_classes();
    foreach ($get_classes as $key => $class) {
        $shipping_classes[ $class->term_id ] = $class->name;
    }

    return apply_filters('woocommerce_multi_packages_settings', array(

        array(  
            'id'        => 'multi-packages_options',
            'type'      => 'title', 
            'title'     => __( 'Multiple Packages for Shipping', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'desc'      => __( 'Separate your customer\'s shopping cart into groups or per product to display multiple shipping select boxes', 'woocommerce' ), 
            ),

        array(
            'id'        => 'multi_packages_enabled',
            'type'      => 'checkbox',
            'title'     => __( 'Enable/Disable', 'bolder-multi-package-woo' ),
            'default'   => 'yes',
            'desc'      => __( 'Enable Multiple Shipping Packages', 'bolder-multi-package-woo' ),
            ),

         array(
            'id'        => 'multi_packages_type',
            'type'      => 'select',
            'title'     => __( 'Group By', 'bolder-multi-package-woo' ),
            'desc'      => __( 'How packages are defined, in groups or per product','bolder-multi-package-woo'),
            'default'   => 'shipping-class',
            'class'     => 'chosen_select',
            'desc_tip'  => true,
            'options'   => array(
                'shipping-class'    => __( 'Shipping Class', 'bolder-multi-package-woo'),
                'per-product'       => __( 'Product (individual)', 'bolder-multi-package-woo' ),
                )
            ),

        array(
            'id'        => 'multi_packages_free_shipping',
            'type'      => 'multiselect',
            'class'     => 'chosen_select',
            'title'     => __( 'Free Shipping Classes', 'bolder-multi-package-woo' ),
            'desc'      => '<em>' . __( '\'Free_Shipping\' method must be enabled', 'bolder-multi-package-woo' ) . '</em>',
            'default'   => __( 'Let me know when this item is back in stock!', 'bolder-multi-package-woo' ),
            'desc_tip'  => __( 'Exclude the selected shipping classes from being charged shipping', 'bolder-multi-package-woo' ),
            'options'   => $shipping_classes,
            ),

        array(
            'id'        => 'shipping_restrictions',
            'type'      => 'shipping_restrictions',
            ),

        array( 'type' => 'sectionend', 'id' => 'multi_packages' ),

        )
    );
}


/**
 * Print Out Additional Settings
 *
 * @return array
 */
function output_additional_settings( $current_section = '' ) {
    // get list of current shipping classes     
    $shipping_classes = array();
    $get_classes = WC()->shipping->get_shipping_classes();
    foreach ($get_classes as $key => $class) {
        $shipping_classes[ $class->term_id ] = $class->name;
    }

    $shipping_methods = WC()->shipping->get_shipping_methods();
    $total_shipping_methods = count( $shipping_methods ) + 1;
?>
        <style>#shipping_package_restrictions .restriction_rows th, #shipping_package_restrictions .restriction_rows td {text-align: center;} #shipping_package_restrictions .class_name {font-weight: bold;text-align: left;}</style>
            <tr valign="top" id="shipping_package_restrictions">
                <th scope="row" class="titledesc"><?php _e( 'Shipping Method Restrictions', 'bolder-multi-package-woo' ); ?>
                    <?php echo wc_help_tip( __('If separating by shipping class, select which shipping methods to use for each class','bolder-multi-package-woo') ); ?>
                    </th>
                <td class="forminp" id="<?php echo $this->id; ?>_restrictions">
                    <table class="restriction_rows widefat" style="width: 60%;min-width:550px;" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <?php foreach ( $shipping_methods as $key => $method ) : ?>
                                <th><?php echo ( method_exists( $method, 'get_method_title' ) ) ? $method->get_method_title() : $method->get_title(); ?></th>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="<?php echo $total_shipping_methods; ?>"><em><?php _e( 'If left blank, all active shipping methods will be used for each shipping class', 'bolder-multi-package-woo' ); ?></em></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                        <tbody class="shipping_restrictions">
<?php
                        $i = -1;
                        if( count( $shipping_classes ) > 0 ) :

                            foreach ( $shipping_classes as $id => $name ) :
?>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="class_name"><?php echo $name; ?></td>
                                <?php foreach ( $shipping_methods as $key => $method ) : ?>
                                <?php $checked = ( isset( $this->package_restrictions[ $id ] ) && in_array( sanitize_title( $key ), $this->package_restrictions[ $id ] ) ) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="restrictions[<?php echo $id; ?>][<?php echo sanitize_title( $key ); ?>]" <?php echo $checked; ?> /></td>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </tr>
<?php
                            endforeach;
                        else :
                            echo '<tr colspan="'.$total_shipping_methods.'">' . _e( 'No shipping classes have been created yet...', 'bolder-multi-package-woo' ) . '</tr>';
                        endif;
?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
<?php
}


/**
 * Output Additional Information
 *
 * @return array
 */
function additional_output( $current_section = '' ) {
?>
        <style>.woocommerce_wrap { position:relative; padding-right: 300px; } a:hover { text-decoration: none; }</style>
        <div class="woocommerce_wrap">
        <div style="position:absolute;top:25px;right:10px;width:275px;display:block;padding:10px;border:1px solid #9dbc5a;border-radius:5px;">
            <h3>Bolder Elements also offers premium plugins! Here are a few you might be interested in...</h3>
            <div style="margin-bottom:25px;">
                <strong>Table Rate Shipping for WooCommerce</strong>
                <p>Has the ability to return multiple rates based on a variety of conditions such as location, subtotal, shipping class, weight, and more</p>
                <p style="text-align:right"><a href="http://codecanyon.net/item/table-rate-shipping-for-woocommerce/3796656?ref=bolderelements" style="color:#9dbc5a;" target="_blank">More Info</a></p>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-bottom:25px;">
                <strong>Bolder Fees for WooCommerce</strong>
                <p>Add extra flat rate, percentage, and even optional (checkbox) fees to the customer's cart. Can be based on subtotal, item details, and more</p>
                <p style="text-align:right"><a href="http://codecanyon.net/item/bolder-fees-for-woocommerce/6125068?ref=bolderelements" style="color:#9dbc5a;" target="_blank">More Info</a></p>
            </div>
            <div style="">
                <strong>Cart Based Shipping for WooCommerce</strong>
                <p>Allows you to change the shipping rate based on the customer's cart. Could be based on the subtotal, item count, or weight.</p>
                <p style="text-align:right"><a href="http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-cart-based-shipping/3156515?ref=bolderelements" style="color:#9dbc5a;" target="_blank">More Info</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
}


/**
 * Print Out Additional Settings
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function sanitize_shipping_restrictions_field( $value, $option, $raw_value ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['restrictions'] ) ) {

        // Save settings
        $restrictions_safe = array();
        foreach ($_POST['restrictions'] as $key => $value) {
            $key_safe = intval( $key );
            foreach ($value as $key_method => $value_method) {
                $restrictions_safe[ $key_safe ][] = sanitize_title( $key_method );
            }
        }

        update_option( $this->multi_package_restrictions, $restrictions_safe );
        $this->get_package_restrictions();

        return $restrictions_safe;
    }
}


/**
 * Get Settings for Restrictions Table
 *
 * @access public
 * @return void
 */
function get_package_restrictions() {
    $this->package_restrictions = array_filter( (array) get_option( $this->multi_package_restrictions ) );
}

}

endif;

return new BE_Multiple_Packages_Settings();
```

And finally here are 2 screenshots demonstrating the problem:

- Example 1:
  [image: Example 1]
- Example 2:
  [image: Example 2]

Comment: Is not possible to test that… What or where is class-settings.php file? … If it's a plugin you should provide the code of the files with all dependencies, just as they are in the related plugin folder.

Answer (score 0):

After some help, my issue has been solved. The Problem was I was calling my shipping class from the cart rather than the package. the correct code is this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'wf_hide_shipping_method_based_on_miele_freestanding_shipping_class', 10, 2);

function wf_hide_shipping_method_based_on_miele_freestanding_shipping_class($available_shipping_methods, $package)
{
$hide_when_shipping_class_exist = array(
    4048 => array(                      // number is shipping class
        'flat_rate:17',                 // set the options you want to hide when this class is in the basket
    'flat_rate:23',
    'flat_rate:22',
    'flat_rate:21',
    'local_pickup:25',
    'free_shipping:16'
    )
);    

$shipping_class_in_cart = array();
foreach($package['contents'] as $key => $values) {
   $shipping_class_in_cart[] = $values['data']->get_shipping_class_id();
}

foreach($hide_when_shipping_class_exist as $class_id => $methods) {
    if(in_array($class_id, $shipping_class_in_cart)){
        foreach($methods as & $current_method) {
            unset($available_shipping_methods[$current_method]);
        }
    }
}
foreach($hide_when_shipping_class_not_exist as $class_id => $methods) {
    if(!in_array($class_id, $shipping_class_in_cart)){
        foreach($methods as & $current_method) {
            unset($available_shipping_methods[$current_method]);
        }
    }
}
return $available_shipping_methods;
}
```

So when working with multiple packages, this now calls the shipping class using '$package['contents']'

Hopefully this will help others out there!